# httpd.conf edit needed if add-on domain used for magento multistore?

Tags: apache, magento, cpanel, httpd.conf

Trying to set up Magento multistore so that the second store, uses a new / different domain name.

Just wondering whether I need to edit the httpd.conf file in a cPanel environment if I have created a 'Add-on' domain for the original Magento installation?

I seem to be confusing myself with the mass of various ways of setting up multistore that I could find online so if someone could advise on the above that would be great please.

Apologies in advance if this should have been posted at the servers exchange site.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Magento version is > 1.3, you need only to set one or two environment variables to trigger the correct store/website based on your configuration. From `index.php`:

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';


Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

`SetEnv` and `SetEnvIf` are good options, as most servers have `mod_env` enabled.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Ben. Yes Magento version is 1.6.2. I've currently added SetEnvIf Host .*domain\.com* MAGE_RUN_CODE=base and 
SetEnvIf Host .*domain\.com* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website in the .htaccess. Where I have created the add-on domain, I copied the .htaccess and index.php into the directory it created for the new domain and also edited the index.php at root level to include exactly what you have provided. Not a lot seems to be happening though unfortunately.

Comment: If the addon is under a different directory, you will need to add symlinks for the folders under the Magento instance. Also, the run code & logic should be for whatever store/website is not the default.

Comment: The symlinks I haven't set up yet so I'll do that - thanks. In .htaccess I have instance for original store and the new store. In the root index.php, just to clarify, should this be the code for the new store (in '') and the 'store' needs to be replaced with the name of the store? Many thanks.

Comment: index.php is designed to not be edited. The idea is that you use your web server software to set the $_SERVER variables which are evaluated in index.php.

Comment: Oh. Nearly every documentation for Magento multistore online specifies the requirement to make a change in the index.php file. Does something such as [this](http://www.crucialwebhost.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/#addon-domain-method) not sound like the correct procedure then? Thanks again Ben.

Comment: That article is from 2008 and was correct at the time (Magento <= CE1.3) See [CE1.3 index.php](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.3/index.php) vs [CE1.4 index.php](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.4/index.php).

Comment: This is the problem I've faced, all the tutorials/content on configuring multistore is somewhat varied depending on server type and Magento versions. I've not managed to find an 'official' correct set of instructions for =>CE1.6 unfortunately.